# Why am I unable to save my UIFontDescriptor into a variable?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uikit, uifont, uifontdescriptor

I have the following code:

```
UIFontDescriptor *fd = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:[[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]].fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold|UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic];
```

But it gives me the error "Expected expression". What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I counted 4 open brackets and 3 close brackets, which will cause an error. Additionally, `fontWithDescriptor:` should be `fontWithDescriptor:size:`, which is probably the expected expression.

Finally, using `fontWithDescriptor:size:` to define a font, then asking for its descriptor is redundant, so a cleaner version of the command is this:

```
UIFontDescriptor *fd = [[[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]] fontDescriptor] fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold|UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic];
```